# svelte bind and the value is not accepted by startWith() filter function to search text

Tags: javascript, svelte

Very strange issue but I'm unable to figure it out. I

I'm trying to create text search in a svelte component. I need to return all words that starts with a specific letter. So includes and indexOf are not suitable as they return the first item only and not return multiple items.

My component script code :

```
<script>
$: searchingfor = []
//let searchterm = ""
$: searchterm = ""

let arr = ["can","can't", "also", "before", "eternal", "anothera"]

function  findterm() {

    let search = arr.filter(el=> el.startsWith("c"))
    console.log("search results :", search)
    
    search.map(el => searchingfor.push(el))
     searchingfor=searchingfor
    
    console.log("searchingfor results in onMount :", searchingfor)
       
}
    
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={searchterm} />
<button on:click={findterm}>Search</button>
```

This code will run and return the correct values because I specifically entered "c" in startWith() fn.

The searchingfor array gets all the words that satisfy the search term. I use each block and display the results

But I want to user to enter what they're searchign for, so I added an input and bind the value to searchterm variable. Now when I type something in the search input and hit enter, I get an empty array.

Console log is showing the value I enter - a - as just a without the double quotation. I don't know how to wrap the searchterm to be wrapped in a "" so I can pass it to startWith()

How do I do that in js? Turn a to "a"?
I tried searchterm = """ +  searchterm + """  but it is creating a empty space before a like this  " a" and again, I'm getting an empty array back from search.

How I get the searchterm value and turn it into "searchterm", or how to search the text for whatever the user entered in the search input?

I'm stomped. Searching text and returning every word that starts with a letter was suppose to be an easy task ;)

Comment: If ```searchterm``` is **undefined** or **null**, the ```startsWith()``` will return an empty array, so make sure that ```searchterm``` is defined and **has a value** before you use in ```startsWith()```.

Comment: Thanks. That got me to think about it and I added async await inside the search fn and it worked. Excellent thinking. Thank you. I'll accept it as an answer if you can provide it in a seperate answer. I'm not able to accept a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you can provide it in a seperate answer.

Sample execution;

```
<script>
 let searchterm = "";
 let arr = ["can","can't", "also", "before", "eternal", "anothera"];

 function findterm() {
   if (searchterm) { // Check if searchterm is not empty
     let search = arr.filter(el => el.startsWith(searchterm));
     console.log("search results :", search);
     return search;
   }
 }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={searchterm} />
<button on:click={findterm}>Search</button>
```

Here, `findterm` checks if `searchterm` is not empty before filtering the `arr` for elements that start with the `searchterm` string. This will prevent the `startsWith()` from returning an empty array when `searchterm` is **undefined** or **null**.